# Problem with adding record using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I try to add a record to SQLServer db table using LINQ to SQL in my WPF app, but always get an error regarding missing directive. Usually intellisense gives a hint on such issue, but not this time. Here my code with all directives:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
...
...
 DateTime newdate = new DateTime(2010, 2, 1);
 TimeSpan newtime = new TimeSpan(12, 00, 00);    

        MyfirstdbDataContext context = new MyfirstdbDataContext();
        Meeting meeting = new Meeting();
        meeting.MeetID = "01.02.10_12:00";
        meeting.Date = newdate;
        meeting.Time = newtime;
        context.Meetings.Add(meeting); // Here I get the debugger error
        context.SubmitChanges();
```

And I get this error:

***System.Data.Linq.Table' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Linq.Table' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)***

Please, what could be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
context.Meetings.InsertOnSubmit(meeting);
```

Answer (score 7):

You should not be getting a debugger error. You should be getting a compile-time error as there is not a `Table.Add` method. Some books/blogs (cf. especially Scott Guthrie's LINQ to SQL [tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/11/linq-to-sql-part-4-updating-our-database.aspx#3106580)) that went to press before LINQ to SQL was finalized will use this syntax but it was replaced by [`Table.InsertOnSubmit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx). Replace your code by the following:

```
context.Meetings.InsertOnSubmit(meeting);
```

Here is the announcement that `Add` was renamed to `InsertOnSubmit`: [LINQ: "Add" renamed to "InsertOnSubmit"](http://blogs.msdn.com/jongallant/archive/2007/12/01/linq-add-renamed-to-insertonsubmit.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Jason! And you are right, it was a compile-time error - not a run-time one. It was my incorrect using of terms, thanks for clearing!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a System.Data.Linq using statement.

Comment: Also, the Add() method was replaced late in the beta with InsertOnSubmit()